# How to make my tabBar icon to show and tinted

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to design tab bar icons for an iOS 7 app, so I followed the HIG and I draw a 76x76 401px in white colour and transparent background .png icon that I imported successfully in my project. Then I selected it on the attribute inspector and successfully appeared in the iOS simulator but when I'm pressing the tab bar icon in the simulated app the title become tinted and the draw disappear. How can I make my draw to show and become tinted too. 
[first link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxzUO.png)
[second link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5h9u.png)

Comment: Please update with screenshots. Both, the required design and the result you're getting.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images. I need another one reputation to post any image.

Comment: You can upload to any website like imgur.com and include the link here.

Comment: have you tried adding an image for the selected state?

Comment: I hope the images are accessible this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're setting the "Selected Image" property on the "Tab Bar Item". It should be left empty if you want the selected image to show up as expected.

[image]